# How to display for user that his wishlist is empty?

Tags: django

**Question like in title.**

When i tried this views.py, error doesn't occur but site doesn't want to show, the page is displayed as source code. Any solutions?

```
def wishlist(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = request.user.id
        if List.objects.filter(user=user).exists():
            context = List.objects.filter(user=user)
            error = 'Your wishlist is empty'
        else:
            context = List.objects.filter(user=user)
    else:
        context = WishList(request)
    return render(request, 'wishlist/wishlist.html', {'wishlist': context}, {'error': error})
```

Comment: you need to swap the `if` and `else`, but regardless, can you provide the template, this can be handled effective in the template.

Comment: I know, but i don't know how exactly by using Jinja, that's why i made this question.

Comment: in Jinja it is the same, you can work with a `{% for ... %} ... {% empty %} ... {% endfor %}` structure which makes rendering and the view simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main errors here:

1. your condition checks if there is any wishlist, so the error should be placed in the `else` part, not the `if` part; and
2. you pass multiple variables to the context by passing it as a dictionary with multiple items.

```
def wishlist(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = request.user.id
        context = List.objects.filter(user=user)
        if context:
            error = None
        else:
            error = 'Your wishlist is empty'
    else:
        context = WishList(request)
    return render(
        request,
        'wishlist/wishlist.html',
        {'wishlist': context, 'error': error}
    )
```

By checking the truthiness of `context`, we will make only one query to fetch all the lists, not two where we first check if the list is empty, and then another one to retrieve data.

Comment: Ok i can see i did a stupid mistake in rush. Thanks for answear.